# Pass argument to sbt task

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following sbt task that I'd like to pass an argument to:

```
import sbt.complete._
import complete.DefaultParsers._

val stageEnv: Parser[String] = " staging" 
val prodEnv : Parser[String] = " production"
val combinedParser: Parser[String] = stageEnv | prodEnv

slick := slickCodeGenTask.value

lazy val slick = inputKey[InputTask[Seq[File]]]("gen-tables")

lazy val slickCodeGenTask = Def.inputTask {
  ...
  s.log.info(combinedParser.parsed.trim)
  Seq(file(fname))
}
```

However, when I run it and pass an arg like 'sbt slick prodEnv' I get the following error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: prodEnv
[error] Not a valid project ID: prodEnv
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: prodEnv (similar: products)
[error] prodEnv
[error]
```

Comment: I think `sbt 'slick prodEnv'` will work.

Comment: @AssenKolov Thanks, still getting similar error though - error] Not a valid command: slick

Comment: So, it is not about parameters but you are not seeing your task at all? Are you sure you have published the latest version?

Comment: Yes the task is running fine, just not seeing the arg

Comment: I have put almost the same question on SO 2 weeks ago. I realised I should call the task either interactive or `sbt 'task args'` and it worked so that I removed the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596401/how-to-create-a-task-that-prints-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
import complete.DefaultParsers._

val slick = inputKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")

slick := {
  ...
  val arg: String = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed(0)
  ... 
}
```

The call with:

sbt 'slick staging'

sbt 'slick production'